# How do I find the confidence interval for the MLE of a Bradley Terry Model?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, fisher-information

I am trying to find out how to find the confidence interval of the Bradley Terry Model. I have the log likelihood equation, and I know I need to use the Fisher Information which is the negative Hessian matrix, however I am unsure what to do next. I also intend to program this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.